# Unable to add IPv6 Address to existing Azure Network Interface

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I am unable to associate a IPv6 public address to an existing network interface for a VM.

When I try to add a secondary IP configuration for the IPv6 address I get the following error:

> IP version for Public IP address and network interface IP configuration version must match.

As seen here:

[image]

However I believe I have everything set up correctly.

The address space on the virtual network has an IPv6 prefix:

[image]

And the subnet is configured with IPv6 address space:

[image]

I tried the answer suggested in this semi-related question but it did not help: [Adding a public IPv6 address to a Linux VM in Azure](https://serverfault.com/questions/1014465/adding-a-public-ipv6-address-to-a-linux-vm-in-azure)